# How did a few blacks and Indians attain good education during apartheid in Cape Town?

Tags: south-africa, apartheid

How did they attain a good education without going to boarding schools or spending money on it? I am talking about both, high school, and college. The timeline is between 1940-1960. During this time there was the Bantu Education Act which segregated education facilities and hindered providing an adequate education. But some still got a good education.

For example, Desmond Tutu. He excelled at school. I am looking for specific examples where the teachers were educated enough to teach well. Maybe Missionary schools, but again they were closed due to the Bantu act.

Another example of Abraham Lincoln. He didn't go to a boarding school or spend money on it.

We know that the University of Cape Town allowed blacks. But was there any fee charged? If yes, then how much?

Comment: Please let us know where you have looked already so that others do not waste time checking sources you've already looked at. Thank you.

Comment: @LarsBosteen For example, Desmond Tutu. He excelled at school.

Comment: @Jos Not possible in my story.

Comment: That's something you should put in your question.

Comment: Alternatively, they could go overseas or be taught by parents/relatives/friends. Are you looking for specific examples? [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desmond_Tutu#Childhood:_1931%E2%80%931950) describes Desmond Tutu's childhood in some detail; his father was a school principal. I'm sure you can find information on other Black leaders.

Comment: @StuartF Yes, I am looking for specific examples where the teachers were educated enough to teach well. Maybe Missionary schools, but again they were closed due to the Bantu act.

Comment: @user324713, First,  please don't reply in comments.  The more comments are present the less likely you are to get an answer.  Edit the question to address the comment then flag for deletion.   (I've taken the liberty of adding your comments into the question; please revise till your comfortable and then flag comments for deletion.)Second, please document your preliminary research.

Comment: How did Abraham Lincoln get a good education? He didn't go to a boarding school or spend money on it.

Comment: @JonCuster Exactly!

Answer (score 2):

Obviously some attained degrees overseas or in neighbouring countries. However it was possible to study at the prior open universities with a [permit](https://www.politicsweb.co.za/news-and-analysis/apartheid-and-the-universities) from the minister. Such permits usually required that the student was gifted and that there wasn't a segregated university offering the main subject of the degree.

There were also the segregated universities so it's not like they didn't have access to higher education.

As for the rest of your question added, free education wasn't like it is today. Whether you were black or white if you didn't come from a wealthy family pretty much your only chance of further education was to get a bursary.

Comment: This is quite helpful! Thank you for this : ). But could they have a permit for high schools and libraries?

Comment: @user324713 As I understand it the permit applied to universities. I am not familiar with the state of education prior to this and where Bantu education started but it was not so much about what blacks were allowed to learn but about what Verwoerd saw them as being capable of.